# How can I implement my explicit override outside the class declaration?

Tags: c++, interface, overriding, visual-studio-2005, definition

I have two classes with the same pure virtual method:

```
class InterfaceA
{
    public: virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};
class InterfaceB
{
    public: virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};
```

And I have a class that derives from these interfaces. I want to override
each virtual function. I can do it this way (this works):

```
class ConcreteClass : public InterfaceA, public InterfaceB
{
    public:

    void InterfaceA::doSomething() override
    {
        printf( "In ConcreteClass::InterfaceA::doSomething()\n" );
    }

    void InterfaceB::doSomething() override
    {
        printf( "In ConcreteClass::InterfaceB::doSomething()\n" );
    }
};
```

My question is however, how can I have my methods' definitions outside the class declaration? So I can have them in my .cpp file. I tried this first:

```
// .h
class ConcreteClass : public InterfaceA, public InterfaceB
{
    public:

    void InterfaceA::doSomething() override;
    void InterfaceB::doSomething() override;
};
// .cpp
void ConcreteClass::InterfaceA::doSomething()
{
    printf( "In ConcreteClass::InterfaceA::doSomething()\n" );
}
void ConcreteClass::InterfaceB::doSomething()
{
    printf( "In ConcreteClass::InterfaceB::doSomething()\n" );
}
```

This doesn't compile in Visual C++ 2005 (VS 2005):

```
error C2509: 'doSomething' : member function not declared in 'ConcreteClass'
```

Does it require a specific sintax in order to be compiled?

Microsoft's MSDN documentation has a working example. But they use their __interface extension. I want to achieve the same but code that complies with standard c++03, if it is even possible.

Thanks!

Comment: the `override` keyword is a c++11 feature, and VS 2005 uses a compiler written before that specification was created. It's not actually required to specify `override`though to implement the virtual functions. I'd suggest trying to just remove the keyword.

Comment: @Nicolas The one I am using is the MS extension used back then. I should probably not use it for this example to make it clearer. But yeah, removing it doesn't fix the problem :( Thanks

Comment: OK, so your problem is actually with the similarly-named functions coming from two interfaces?

Comment: @Nicolas, What I want to do is move the method definitions to my .cpp file, outside the class declaration. The function having the same name is not the issue, in fact, it is what I want. Ta

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's not exactly what you are looking for, the obvious workaround is to dispatch to helper functions:

```
class ConcreteClass : public InterfaceA, public InterfaceB
{
public:
    void InterfaceA::doSomething() override {
        InterfaceA_doSomething();
    }

    void InterfaceB::doSomething() override {
        InterfaceB_doSomething();
    }

 private:
    void InterfaceA_doSomething();
    void InterfaceB_doSomething();
};
```